# Multiple requests being send unintentionally

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, xampp, phpmailer, amazon-ses

I am using a PHP Script written by me with AWS (Amazon Web Service) PHP Script to send emails using SMTP

Everytime I run this script, say I have 3 user's in my database, then the first user get's mail of the first, second and third person. The second user get's mail to second and third person. And the third user get's the mail to the third person only.

I don't know why this is happening, and been pulling my hair for some time. Maybe I am missing some point, that is why adding a question here.

Pre-Requisites:

func1() = Is used to get emails from DB whom I have not send Emails Yet, return's a single value (ID) only

func2() = Is used to get the data of that particular user whose ID was found in func1()

func3() = Is used to mark "Send" to that particular ID whom we send the mail.

```
<?php

require 'aws-autoloader.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;    
$mail->isSMTP();    
$mail->setFrom('myemail@address.com', 'My Company Name');    
$mail->Username = 'Username';    
$mail->Password = 'Password';    
$mail->Host = 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';

class Db {
    public function dbconnect(){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "database";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        return $conn;
    }
    public function func1()
    {
    $conn=$this->dbconnect();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL func1()");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=NULL;
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $item=NULL;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
        {
        $item[] = $row;
        }
    return $item;
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    }
    public function func2($id)
    {
    $conn=$this->dbconnect();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL func2(?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $item=NULL;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
        {
        $item[] = $row;
        }
    return $item;
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    }
    public function func3($id)
    {
    $conn=$this->dbconnect();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL func3(?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $item=NULL;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM))
        {
        $item[] = $row;
        }
    return $item;
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
    }
}
$count=0;
$obj=new Db;
$ids=$obj->func1();
while(($ids[0][0]!=0)&&($count<1000)){
$ids=$obj->func1();
$rslt=$obj->func2($ids[0][0]);
if($rslt[0][0]!=NULL)
    {
    $idno=$rslt[0][0];
    $companyname=$rslt[0][2];
    $email=$rslt[0][16];
    $complete=NULL;
do{
    $mail->addAddress($email, $companyname);
    $mail->Subject = 'My Subject';
    $mail->Body = '<p>Hello</p>';
    $mail->AltBody = "Hello";

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Email not sent. " , $mail->ErrorInfo , PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        $complete=$obj->func3($ids[0][0]);
    }
}while($complete[0][0]!=3);
}
$count=$count+1;
//if($count%10==0) Trying to give a small break after each 10 emails are send
    sleep(1);
}
$count=$count-1;
echo 'Email Send to: '.$count.' Users.<br>';
?>
```

After the function is called, I receive emails as described at the start. And all the users are marked "Send"

Any Idea what I may be doing wrong to get result like that.

Comment: Perhaps because you're adding an email address each iteration using $mail->addAddress() without resetting the list of email addresses hence the list of recipients is growing each time.

Comment: Yup, that makes sense, do you know how to reset it?

Comment: The docs suggest you can call $mail->clearAddresses()  or $mail->clearAllRecipients() or you could create a new PHPMailer object for each email.

Comment: Can you please tell me where did you read that?

Comment: The docs seem to be pretty slim, but I found this: http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html

Comment: Can you write this as an answer so that I can upvote and accept your answer. Thank You for the help!

Comment: Look at the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer which shows how to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using the same [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html) object for each email, and it is adding addresses using `$mail->addAddress()` without resetting the list of email addresses between emails hence the list of recipients is growing each time.

You can call `$mail->clearAllRecipients()` for each new email or you could create a new PHPMailer object for each email. Note that if you choose the former approach then you should check to see if there are any other things that also need to be reset from one email to the next.